# Remove duplicate values from array based on a value in a nested array

Tags: php, arrays, key-value

I would like to compare an array of records in order to find those with a common identity stored in the record. The record is implemented as an associative array. If multiple records exist for any identity, I want to remove the record with lower value from the array.

I'll try to explain it on the example.

Here is example array. You can see there is two times same "ean". 
I need to find all arrays with **same "ean"** and compare **their "productCount"**. Then I need to remove array which has a **lower productCount value**.

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [ean] => **6909536610216**
        [productPrice] => 760
        [productCount] => 107
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [ean] => 6909536610261
        [productPrice] => 779
        [productCount] => 128
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [ean] => **6909536610216**
        [productPrice] => 920
        [productCount] => 20
    )


function removeduplicateKeys($data){

    $_data = array();

    foreach ($data as $v) {
      if (isset($_data[$v['ean']])) {
        // found duplicate
        continue;
      }
      // remember unique item
      $_data[$v['ean']] = $v;
    }

    $data = array_values($_data);
    return $data;
 }
```

So output should be

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [ean] => 6909536610261
        [productPrice] => 779
        [productCount] => 128
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [ean] => **6909536610216**
        [productPrice] => 920
        [productCount] => 20
    )
```

Can you help me please? Thank you

Comment: Can you show what you've tried and where you got stuck? SO is **not** a free coding service.

Comment: So, what's the problem? Iterate over array, compare values, do stuff.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your next experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)
 **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write it for you**

Comment: I tried it. Now I can remove a array with same ean but can't compar it by productCount

Comment: Ok, so show us the code you have and someone will almost definitely point you in the right direction. Edit the question, dont add code in a comment

Comment: This looks like the XY problem - the data appears to come from a database and that is where you should be starting your data management. In terms of presenting the right data to the application, use ean as the array key.

Comment: the data comes from a xml file wich is generated by accounting software then SimpleXMLElement converts them to array.